# Which one sounds better to say?

Tags: word-choice, difference

on the waves?
in the waves?

Which one is better to write for names and sounds good to say to people.

Comment: This question is unclear because it lacks context for these phrases. If you could provide the full sentences that this phrase would be part of it would help get you a good answer.

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised to see [*just how **equally** common*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+waves%2Cin+the+waves&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20waves%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20waves%3B%2Cc0) both prepositions are.

Answer (score 1):

It depends - what are you doing in/on the waves

**in the waves** for swimming, diving, wading, playing water football
**on the waves** for surfing, landing a floatplane